# Linear Algebra, under what condition is the system not consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Scouring the internet for extra practice problems I ran on a random homework packet without answers.  Most I can generally check my own work one way or another but this one has me confused:

> For the system below to be consistent what value can $k$ NOT be equal to?
> $$−x + 8y = h$$
> $$−4x + ky = 2$$

I can't imagine a situation where $k$ changes if the set of equations is consistent or not.  Worst case in RREF it can be zero but if the augmented value on it's line is also zero that's consistent and dependent.  Have I missed something?  The previous question asked the values of k and h where the system has zero solutions so it's hard to imagine it's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations given to you are $$-4x + 32y = 4h \tag{1}$$ $$-4x + ky = 2 \tag{2}$$
Think about the situation **geometrically**. It is easy to do so since there are just $2$ variables, and one can imagine the two equations above as lines in $\mathbb R^2$. There is no need to invoke the strength of linear algebra.

If the lines $(1)$ and $(2)$ coincide, that is, $k = 32$ and $h = \frac12$, then the system has infinitely many solutions. If the lines are not parallel, i.e. $k \ne 32$, then they shall intersect, and you will obtain a unique solution. The troublesome case (where consistency says goodbye) is when the lines are *parallel, but not coinciding.* In analytic terms, this means $k = 32$ and $h \ne \frac12$.

So, as the question asks: $k$ *cannot* be equal to $32$ if $h \ne \frac12$.

Comment: Okay, so there is no condition where k alone could make the system of equations consistent or non-consistent?  That's what I thought the question was asking for and I got confused.

Comment: @foreverska If $k \ne 32$, then the system is necessarily consistent (regardless of what $h$ is). If $k = 32$, we cannot be sure; we have to check what $h$ is, to be able to decide.